# Twilio : Not able to create two way voice communication

Tags: twilio, outbound

I am using following link to make a out bound call from my twillio account :

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/rest/call-request

I am able to play predfined voicexml but not able to get response from the target device ( receving device) can you please suggest me the way I can make two way communication with the target device .

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to make a two way call, you need to update the URL and supply your own XML that returns an instruction to Twilio to `<Dial>` onto your target device. [Check out the documentation for `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) and this [tutorial on a "click to call" feature](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/java/servlets) that should help you out with this.